# Can't pass data in function in React

Tags: reactjs

I pass data to my function in react, but when i show log, it is undefined.
Parent:

```
export const getDomainList = ({ page, page_size}, callback = (code, response) => { }) => {
    console.log(page, page_size);
...
};
```

child:

```
 props.getDomainList( 1, 25, (code, res) => handleResult(code, res));
```

Answer (score 2):

You are passing property as destructing assignment ([doc](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment#Unpacking_fields_from_objects_passed_as_a_function_parameter)). Child call must be

```
props.getDomainList({page: 1, page_size: 25}, (code, res) => handleResult(code, res));
```